# Monkeyrunner Unable to acces jarfile ..\framework\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar

Tags: windows-10, command-line, java

I'm trying to use the monkeyrunner tool. I got  sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip [latest version at the time writting] . After I extracted the .zip , I tried to run monkeyrunner in CMD and it said **Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar** .

To fix it , I set the path to **tools/lib/x86_64** . This fixed the issue , but another one appeared : 
**Error: Unable to access jarfile ..\framework\monkeyrunner-26.0.0-dev.jar**

I've found some "fixes" while googlin' , but none of them work . If I change the .bat file to remove a line and add something else ,  I just end up with an error thats **Exception in main...**  and something about chimpchat and from there and I found a fix for that , but from there it gives me another issue.

I tried a fix that implies to copy the file in *lib/x86_64* into *lib/x86* and then set the path to the *lib/x86* . This fix didn't work

I don't know how monkeyrunner tools is intended to use when from a fresh installation , it just gives off errors.